# HTML/ CSS: How to create a scrollable horizontal list of checkboxes

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a form with checkboxes lined horizontally that can be scrolled left/right, while maintaining that each checkbox is styled to look like a button. (as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zAFND/2/))

Unfortunately, the checkboxes keep wrapping onto the next line and I can't figure out why.

Here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/markocalvocruz/55jp59ho/

I was using this website as a reference:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_menu_hor_scroll

The link aboveworks with a list of  tags as shown. My guess is that there is an issue with applying `display: inline-box` to a `<label>` tag. I tried to replace `<label>`  with `<span>` but then I am unable to make the checkboxes look as I want them to (and it doesn't fix the problem either).

Comment: the css `white-space: nowrap;` may help, along with `overflow-x: scroll;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap all `.ck-button` divs under another div with `id="container"`, then add following css

```
#container{
width:2000px;
}
```

and for your buttons do the following:

```
.dates form .ck-button label{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.dates .ck-button input:checked + span{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Comment: You rock. Thank you. If this were bootstrap, would the width need to be specified?

Comment: I am not sure about it!

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is not bootstrap compatible. Since I already marked this as a solve problem, I created a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49783588/bootstrap-html-css-create-a-scrollable-horizontal-list-of-checkboxes?noredirect=1#comment86582804_49783588