# Bootstrap & HTML/CSS: Create a Scrollable Horizontal List of Checkboxes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**UPDATE: DESIRED OUTCOME**
[image: desired outcome]

**CURRENT STATUS**
[image: current]
I recently asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49780867/html-css-how-to-create-a-scrollable-horizontal-list-of-checkboxes/49781053?noredirect=1#comment86577618_49781053) that is very similar to this one, except without Bootstrap.

The solution, which is posted below, depended upon wrapping the list of checkboxes around a `<div id="container">` with `width: 2000px` http://jsfiddle.net/markocalvocruz/55jp59ho/18/

However, the solution does not work using Bootstrap.

I want the list to span the full width of Bootstrap's container and this breaks when the width value changes/ the id is removed. It currently scrolls, but there are two lines instead of 1.

The wrapping gets worse if I make the .ck-box bigger as well

This is my code (removed`width:2000px`):

```
#index.html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <img class="date-scroll" src="/assets/LeftScroll-5090a173eda2e839d00923366dad5c510b34d5f60312573e77dfba19a1f92648.png" alt="Leftscroll">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="dates">
          <form class="event_search" id="event_search" action="/events" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
            <div id="dates">
                <div class="ck-button">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q[events_start_dt_matches_any][]" id="q_events_start_dt_matches_any_" value="2018-03-26" checked="checked">
                    <span>
                      Mar <br>
                      26
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ck-button">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q[events_start_dt_matches_any][]" id="q_events_start_dt_matches_any_" value="2018-03-27" checked="checked">
                    <span>
                      Mar <br>
                      27
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ck-button">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q[events_start_dt_matches_any][]" id="q_events_start_dt_matches_any_" value="2018-03-28" checked="checked">
                    <span>
                      Mar <br>
                      28
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ck-button">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q[events_start_dt_matches_any][]" id="q_events_start_dt_matches_any_" value="2018-03-29" checked="checked">
                    <span>
                      Mar <br>
                      29
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ck-button">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q[events_start_dt_matches_any][]" id="q_events_start_dt_matches_any_" value="2018-03-30" checked="checked">
                    <span>
                      Mar <br>
                      30
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ck-button">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q[events_start_dt_matches_any][]" id="q_events_start_dt_matches_any_" value="2018-03-31" checked="checked">
                    <span>
                      Mar <br>
                      31
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ck-button">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q[events_start_dt_matches_any][]" id="q_events_start_dt_matches_any_" value="2018-04-01" checked="checked">
                    <span>
                      Apr <br>
                      1
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ck-button">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q[events_start_dt_matches_any][]" id="q_events_start_dt_matches_any_" value="2018-04-02" checked="checked">
                    <span>
                      Apr <br>
                      2
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ck-button">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q[events_start_dt_matches_any][]" id="q_events_start_dt_matches_any_" value="2018-04-03" checked="checked">
                    <span>
                      Apr <br>
                      3
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ck-button">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q[events_start_dt_matches_any][]" id="q_events_start_dt_matches_any_" value="2018-04-04" checked="checked">
                    <span>
                      Apr <br>
                      4
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ck-button">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q[events_start_dt_matches_any][]" id="q_events_start_dt_matches_any_" value="2018-04-05" checked="checked">
                    <span>
                      Apr <br>
                      5
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ck-button">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q[events_start_dt_matches_any][]" id="q_events_start_dt_matches_any_" value="2018-04-06" checked="checked">
                    <span>
                      Apr <br>
                      6
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ck-button">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q[events_start_dt_matches_any][]" id="q_events_start_dt_matches_any_" value="2018-04-07" checked="checked">
                    <span>
                      Apr <br>
                      7
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ck-button">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q[events_start_dt_matches_any][]" id="q_events_start_dt_matches_any_" value="2018-04-08" checked="checked">
                    <span>
                      Apr <br>
                      8
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ck-button">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q[events_start_dt_matches_any][]" id="q_events_start_dt_matches_any_" value="2018-04-09" checked="checked">
                    <span>
                      Apr <br>
                      9
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ck-button">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q[events_start_dt_matches_any][]" id="q_events_start_dt_matches_any_" value="2018-04-10" checked="checked">
                    <span>
                      Apr <br>
                      10
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ck-button">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q[events_start_dt_matches_any][]" id="q_events_start_dt_matches_any_" value="2018-04-11" checked="checked">
                    <span>
                      Apr <br>
                      11
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ck-button">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q[events_start_dt_matches_any][]" id="q_events_start_dt_matches_any_" value="2018-04-12" checked="checked">
                    <span>
                      Apr <br>
                      12
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ck-button">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q[events_start_dt_matches_any][]" id="q_events_start_dt_matches_any_" value="2018-04-13" checked="checked">
                    <span>
                      Apr <br>
                      13
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ck-button">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q[events_start_dt_matches_any][]" id="q_events_start_dt_matches_any_" value="2018-04-14" checked="checked">
                    <span>
                      Apr <br>
                      14
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ck-button">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q[events_start_dt_matches_any][]" id="q_events_start_dt_matches_any_" value="2018-04-15" checked="checked">
                    <span>
                      Apr <br>
                      15
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ck-button">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q[events_start_dt_matches_any][]" id="q_events_start_dt_matches_any_" value="2018-04-16" checked="checked">
                    <span>
                      Apr <br>
                      16
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ck-button">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q[events_start_dt_matches_any][]" id="q_events_start_dt_matches_any_" value="2018-04-17" checked="checked">
                    <span>
                      Apr <br>
                      17
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ck-button">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q[events_start_dt_matches_any][]" id="q_events_start_dt_matches_any_" value="2018-04-18" checked="checked">
                    <span>
                      Apr <br>
                      18
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
            </div>
</form>        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <img class="date-scroll" src="/assets/RightScroll-d97f0607dc5f86e60e902b742ba1e9424a7b9b5af74f046aead3c0698ae97bbd.png" alt="Rightscroll">
      </div>
</div>
</div>
```

.

```
style.scss
.dates {
  form {
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;

    .ck-button {

      float:left;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 50px;
      height: 40px;
      border-radius:4px;
      border:1px solid #D0D0D0;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: white;
      margin:4px;

      label {
        display: inline-block;
        color: black;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue";

        span {
          text-align: center;
          vertical-align: center;
          display: inline-block;
        }
        input {
          display: none;
        }
      }
    }


  }
  .ck-button input:checked + span {
    background-color: $shiraz;
    color:#fff;
  }

}

.dates form .ck-button label{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.dates .ck-button input:checked + span{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: this question is about html.. just post you html generated code and post it in the relevant html section.. many people will read it and help you.. just copy the generate html code from your developer toolbar

Comment: Fair point. I edited this question to remove mention of Ruby on Rails

Comment: Your HTML doesn't include any Bootstrap-specific classes, are you sure that Bootstrap is the problem? A minimum test I made seems to work just fine: https://www.bootply.com/uEtDcHlLK1

Comment: The HTML is wrapped inside a `<div class="container"><div class="row"></div></div>`.  I just included that into the main question

Comment: I looked at your link and it still shows two rows of dates, how can we keep it at 1 row? I updated the original question with better pictures to show the desired outcome

Answer (score 0):

The following solution requires you to use Bootstrap v4.x as it takes advantage of `flexbox`.

```css
.checkbox-wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  max-height: 4.25rem;
}

.checkbox-wrapper .checkbox-item {
  margin-right: 0.25rem;
}

.checkbox-wrapper .checkbox-item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.checkbox-item span {
  display: block;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: .5rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
          
.checkbox-item input[type=checkbox]:checked + span {
  background: #d86275;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
    
      <form class="checkbox-wrapper d-flex flex-row">
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none"><span>Mar<br>1</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>2</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>3</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>4</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>5</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>6</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>7</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none"><span>Mar<br>1</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>2</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>3</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>4</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>5</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>6</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>7</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none"><span>Mar<br>1</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>2</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>3</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>4</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>5</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>6</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>7</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none"><span>Mar<br>1</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>2</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>3</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>4</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>5</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>6</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>7</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none"><span>Mar<br>1</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>2</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>3</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>4</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>5</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>6</span></label>
      <label class="checkbox-item text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" class="d-none" checked><span>Mar<br>7</span></label>
      </form>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above code we're relying on Bootstrap 4's built-in utility classes to apply a Flex-based layout structure to the `<form>` (`d-flex` and `flex-row`).  This forces the child items to flow horizontally and ignore any overflow.

From there it's a matter of specifying `overflow-x` and a `max-height` to ensure that the scrollbar appears and the height is consistent.

You'll need to expand on this snippet further in order to achieve your left/right arrows, which I assume are designed to mimic scrolling behavior.  That will likely require additional JavaScript